# What is the meaning of "The whole bigger"?

Tags: the-core-2003

Dr Braz and Josh Keyes tried an experiment on computer 
to see wheather blowing nuke weapon will cause Earth's core 
to start spin again but it didn't create good results. So 
Dr Conrad told his idea:

> Dr Conrad: You drop a large stone into a pond, you get a big  splash,
>   and then that's it, it's over. But drop a smaller stone, wait until
>   the ripples weaken and  drop another and another, and another, and
>   fluid  dynamics 101. The ripples reinforce each other in  geometric
>   progression.
>
> Dr Braz: **The whole bigger** than the sum of the parts.  Then we'll have
>   five 200 megaton explosions...
>
> Dr Conrad: Instead of one big bang.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The whole is better than the sum of it's parts

Is a well known [idiom](http://masterkeyenglish.com/idiom-the-whole-is-greater-than-the-sum-of-the-parts/)

An example would be: An orchestra sounds better than any of the individual musicians playing the piece by themselves

In the case of the movie, the cumulative effect of multiple bombs exploding in a carefully times sequence gives a better effect that one single huge bomb.

Replacing "better" with "bigger" just gives more context to the plot point here.

Comment: Nit: the whole is _greater_ than the sum of its parts (in your link, and also more synonymous with "bigger")