# What caused Dr Josh Keyes to realize timers should be reset?

Tags: the-core-2003

After detonating the last bomb in the last compartment
of submarine ship near the Earth's core. Dr Josh Keyes
and Dr Conrad are discussed each other:

> Dr Conrad: I just took the wavelengths from the core fluid  off the
>   MRI readings.
>
> Dr Josh Keyes: Yeah, and multiplied by 800...
>
> Dr Conrad: Six hundred.
>
> Dr Josh Keyes: Surely you compensated for the MRI bias.

Suddenly Dr Josh Keyes rushed to the last bomb which he just now detonated with Dr Conrad by saying this words to Dr Conrad:

> Dr Josh Keyes: **We got to reset the timers!**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the context of those quotes, and [your other question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/174843/5833), the plan seems to be to precisely time five separate, smaller explosions to end up with a much larger effect than a single larger detonation would achieve.

However, during the quoted discussion he realises that Dr Conrad performed the wrong calculation, multiplying by 600 ("Six hundred") rather than the correct 800; presumably there was some visual cue from Dr Conrad that he'd not "compensated for the MRI bias". That incorrect calculation would in turn lead to the detonation times being set incorrectly (either too early or too late) and the end result wouldn't be what they needed.